# IK constraint not working

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics

This is the robot rig that I am working on. I duplicated the left leg to make an FK IK switch. But the IK is not working on the "Third leg part L.002". I tried to move the IK control bone, which is "Foot L.002", but I am not able to. I can only rotate it and it is not controlling the other bones.

Here is my blender file https://www.mediafire.com/file/bero482tlud01xo/robot_v2_-_rig_-_controls.blend/file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to unlock your controller bone loc channels.

[image]